# heroku error Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: node.js, heroku, puppeteer

I made a scraper with puppeteer and I didn't specified any port for serving it. it just runs and scrape data and exits with `process.exit()` command.

I deployed it to heroku with cli but after running it throw error:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch.
Stopping process with SIGKILL
Process exited with status 137
```

whats wrong?

Comment: Have you applied everything mentioned here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-heroku? (heroku build pack installed, launch flags added)

Comment: yes i added buidpack

Comment: It's not clear when your scraper should run. You'll probably want to use a scheduler or clock. Examples of both are in [Puppeteer on Heroku Error R10 (Boot timeout) Node (webscraping app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67498169/puppeteer-on-heroku-error-r10-boot-timeout-node-webscraping-app/67595949#67595949)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Puppeteer on Heroku Error R10 (Boot timeout) Node (webscraping app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67498169/puppeteer-on-heroku-error-r10-boot-timeout-node-webscraping-app)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a Web Dyno so the app must bind to $PORT.

You can instead define a worker (in the `Procfile`) if you do not need incoming HTTP requests.

Comment: I'm not familiar with worker and Procfile, can you send me an example?